# Importing claims from a (multi tenant) AD tenant into B2C (and subsequently PowerApps Portal)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, multi-tenant, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have set up a custom b2c policy in order for users (specific clients of ours) in specific Azure AD tenants to log into a Portal without having to explicitely sign up first (they can log into the Portal via b2c using their whitelisted AD account).

I wanted to make this happen using basic userflows but as far as I know AD multi tenancy is only possible with custom policies but that's a seperate issue entirely.

What I want to do now is to take the user's attributes as they are set in their AD client (phone number, etc) and add those to the claimsbag in the sign up userjourney so that they will persist in the b2c tenant as well (and in turn map those again to the client contact in the Portal).

I have read up on enriching tokens a lot, as well as using custom attributes but so far I have not been able to find how to actually get the already existing data from the user's AD account and transfer that to the b2c account as it is created on sign up.

Maybe I need to use the Graph API to do this but I have no experience in using APIs to retrieve that data from a user (would need rights and consent as well of course) and more importantly, I don't know (yet) how I would implement/call an API in a userjourney.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated!

If it turns out I can give specific white listed AD users (from different AD tenants) access to sign up to my b2c tenant and import data like (mobile) phone numbers from those users' AD accounts then that would of course be absolutely fantastic.

In terms of code: I am using the XML files (and thus also the user journey) from the local and social starter pack, removing the social login options from the Extensions file, adding only a multi tenant AD claimsprovider (as instructed by MS docs), and removing only some output claims in the self asserted social technical profile in order to hide the data that I am able to import and persist from the user during sign up (name, username, and alternate email (which is also the userprincipalname for some reason)).

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configuring-optional-claims), you configure the optional claims that you want to pass from Azure AD.

Then as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider), you map these claims to the B2C equivalent.

e.g.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
```

On the Azure AD side, you selected "family_name" and "given_name".

On the B2C side, the right-hand side of the mapping is the Azure AD name. The left-hand side is the B2C name.

So "family_name" maps to "surName" in B2C, and you can now use this claim in your user journey.

Comment: The problem with using optional claims from the token configuration setting is that it lacks a lot of attributes that would be very helpful to transfer between the user's AD tenant and their b2c account.
Does adding claim types do anything if those claims (like phone number) arent available to be selected in the token configuration of the registration app? I can add those attributes to a token's claimbag but if the reg. app doesn't transfer/import them, it feels useless.

Comment: You can add extra claims - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#claims-mapping-policy-assignment. However, if that claim is not in the B2C schema (e.g. employeeID in the link), you have to add it as an extension attribute i.e. extension_employeeID.